# How Imitate a [Ctrl+Left mouse click] on the center of the form or open another program and type in a word?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, windows-messages

Babylon dictionary and a couple of other dictionaries allow to click on any word in any windows program
and automatically recognize the word under the cursor, and at once open the dictionary window while searching for that word in installed dictionaries.
You can on the other hand open your dictionary, type in your word and press Enter, the result will be the same.

There's a Delphi form, containing a text label, for example with the word "Automaton".

My question is:

How to send a word from my Delphi application right into the dictionary window, as if you typed it manually and pressed Enter?

The best solution is to send some message through the Windows mechanism, but if it is too complicated, there's another solution, and so the second answer: as I described, we need to model a [Ctrl+left mouse] click on a form where this word is displayed on a form [ a visual label on the screen of my Delphi application], to be exact, on some central pixel of this label.

Could you kindly give an advice how to do one thing or another in Delphi ?

** edit:
The problem with AppActivate is this: Babylon dict has a daemon part that seats in the tray.
In the task manager a real window where the text should be input also is named 'Babylon'.
So AppActivate('Babylon') tries to bring to front the non-visual part of the application.

Do you have any suggestion how to determine the windows handle or something of a real visual part of the application? In the task manager, I repeat both visual and non-visual parts are named 'Babylon'.

Comment: Tried 'SendKeys.pas' and AppActivate() but it does not seem to work with Babylon

Comment: It seems to me that this is actually about Babylon rather than Delphi. The easy bit of any interfacing problem like this is usually in the code that you control. The hard parts are in the code that you don't control. I'd try the Babylon documentation/support forums etc.

Comment: Ok, but still is there any way to position the cursor in the middle of the delphi form's label and simulate Ctrl+left mouse click on that pixel?

Comment: @EugeneP Surely that action ends up in your app rather than Babylon, if you app has the focus.

Comment: @EugeneP Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @EugeneP Ah, perhaps Babylon hooks into other apps which would be one way for them to respond to events that were sent to your windows.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot offer an answer so much as some insight and advice...

There are certain applications which "intercept" keyboard and mouse instructions, and essentially "nullify" them if they are being immitated by software. Generally-speaking, you'd only see this in proper AntiVirus software such as Kaspersky by design... however:

The way some (not many, but some) programs hook keyboard and mouse inputs, as a side-effect, behave the same way. If you have attempted all of the advice given as comments above, and cannot get Babylon to trigger an action as a result, it is likely Babylon behaves as I have described.

If what I suspect is true, then the method you are attempting is simply not possible (at least, not using any simple Pascal code on its own... ASM might be able to do it but that's beyond my knowledge).

A better solution may be to do a little research to see if any of the following options are available to you:
1) Does Babylon have a Pipeline or API you can use to interface your application(s) with it?
2) Is the particular functionality you require of Babylon accessible through one (or more) DLL files distributed as part of Babylon?
3) Is there an alternative to using Babylon for your needs?

I know it's not an answer as such (certainly not one you'd want to hear), but it may point you in a better direction.